# How to make a div to contain two display-cell child divs per row?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a `div` with a computed width of `400px` and I want to insert many child `div`s inside it and all of the child divs have a `table-cell` display and they are all `200px` wide.

However rather than getting to divs per row, they are expanding the size of the parent div. Is there a way to make them automatically start filling the next rows, etc. instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you have to use table-cell property for child divs? If you havent..

```
<div style="width:400px; overflow:auto;">
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">div 1</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">div 2</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">div 3</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">div 4</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left;">div 5</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sASpN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Div's are `display:block;` by default, you can css your inside div's with `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` if you want the save the `block` behavior.
Another way to do that is to give your inside div's the css `float:left;` or `float:right;`

Comment: He's using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: I know... i gave him second option with floats

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout:fixed` to the parent div (the one with `display:table`). This will only work if you set the `width` on that div to something other than `auto`.

Oh, you might also want to add word-wrap: break-word.